# Lucene.Net 3.0.3 Search with stemming or search for best match

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Trying to get the search to work the way i need it... currently i use StandardAnalyzer() to analyze my data into a index after that i use a QueryParser () with a Query() and execute... If a document has the word suspected in it search for "suspected" i will get my doc in it but if i search for "suspect" i'm not getting any results... so my question is i want to implement either stemming or a better query to my searching... I know you get SnowballAnalyzer for stemming but its not available in Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and i'm not sure that there is another query that can provide me with the required searching functionality... i tried using the FuzzyQuery and then it works but it only works for one word searches and not multiple word searches...

*Edit*
How do i implement stemming on Lucene.Net 3.0.3

Comment: A MVCE goes a long way

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer i was looking for in the http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/ package you get highlighter and snowballfilter so i just used the snowballfilter to stem the search term and do wildcard search off of that was pretty easy